# Electric field in a circuit

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, charge

The electric field is defined mathematically as a vector field that associates to each point in space the (electrostatic or Coulomb) force per unit of charge exerted on an infinitesimal positive test charge **at rest at** that point.

In a DC/AC electric circuit, we say that an electric field is set up between terminal of source and so charges move between terminals.

Once charges start moving,can't we anymore say that force that acts on the charge to move it in between terminals is due to Electric field since it is defined for Charges at rest?

Comment: Charges don't move because of the existence of electric field, they move due to difference in electric potential between two points. If the electric field is uniform, the charge will stay. If there is a change in electric field, then charge will move i.e. you will see current.

Comment: @LostCause, how do you produce an difference in electric potential without the existence of electric field? The definition of the electrostatic potential difference is a path integral over the field.

Comment: @LostCause That is like saying "Object's don't fall because of a gravitational field. They fall because of the difference in gravitational potential energy". Plus... charges will definitely move (accelerate) in a uniform electric field, just like how objects fall in a uniform gravitational field.

Comment: @ThePhoton when you solve that integral, you assume that electrostatic potential at infinity is 0. The reason that assumption works well because we don't care about the true value, we only care about the difference.

Comment: @AaronStevens Look at the derivation of gravitational potential energy, it is a relative term. You can assume that the gravitational potential energy at infinity is 100J. All the equations will work just fine with that assumption.

Comment: @LostCause Ok? That doesn't make your first comment correct. You are essentially saying forces don't move things.

Comment: @AaronStevens wait, that doesn't make sense. The charge moves in the direction of field in a uniform field. I am re-reading my comment and now I see your point. My thoughts got jumbled up in my head. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: @LostCause Positive charges accelerate in the direction of any electric field if no other forces are acting on them.

Comment: Yes you are right. I overthought.

Comment: @LostCause, no, the integral gives you a potential difference between two points. It doesn't depend on what you choose as your reference for "zero potential".

Comment: Would you please elaborate on why you believe what you state in your question?  Recall that the [Lorentz force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force) $\mathbf{F}$ on a particle of electric charge $q$ and velocity $\mathbf{v}$ is given by $$\mathbf{F} = q(\mathbf{E} + \mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{B})$$  Note that the electric component of this force has no velocity dependence.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri I felt electric field stops acting after charges moves...But now  I got the right understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The force on the charge due to the electric field doesn't depend on whether the charge is moving or at rest (at least so long as we can neglect relativistic effects).

The reason we might stipulate that the electric field is defined in terms of the force on a test charge **at rest** is not because electric field affects moving charges differently than charges at rest. It's only so that we know the force on the test charge is entirely due to the electric field, and doesn't have any contribution from whatever magnetic field might also be present at the same point.